# Change the working directory for a specific static bound assembly

Tags: c#, .net, dll, .net-assembly

I have a reference to an external assembly DLL (says it is installed at c:\ABC) in the project setting. When I make a call to the exported method from that assembly I get runtime error. Because it is looking for a file c:\ABC\abc.ini while the .exe working directory is at other location.

How to 'fool' only that assembly the current working directory is at c:\ABC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you don't have control over that external assembly (i.e. you can't modify its code), about the only thing you can do is wrap all calls to that assembly with:

```
var currentDir = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
Environment.CurrentDirectory = @"c:\ABC";
try
{
    // call that external assembly
}
finally
{
    Environment.CurrentDirectory = currentDir;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it does not work. Neither does Directory.SetCurrentDirectory

Comment: Oh, i think the assembly does not use the current directory to look for the abc.ini. It uses the Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase or Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location. is it possible to fool it then?

Comment: I post another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27561242/net-assembly-override-the-assembly-getexecutingassembly-codebase-location-of for the Assembly location. This one could be closed. Thanks.