# .Net assembly override the Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase/Location of an external assembly

Tags: c#, .net, app-config, .net-assembly

I have a reference to an external assembly DLL (say I copy it in c:\project\abc.dll) in the project setting. When I make a call to the exported method from that assembly I get runtime error. Because it is looking for a file abc.ini which is in c:\ABC while the .exe error message saying that it cannot find the abc.ini in c:\project

The assembly seems looking for the folder returned by either Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase or Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location for the abc.ini.

How to 'fool' only that assembly his assembly location is at c:\ABC?

Comment: There's no reasonable way to change `GetExecutingAssembly.CodeBase` or `Location`. If you don't have source for the assembly in question, your only solution is to copy your assembly to c:\ABC.

Comment: It seems so. Thanks Jim. Please put it as an Answer and then I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reasonable way to change `GetExecutingAssembly.CodeBase` or `Location`. If you don't have source for the assembly in question, your only solution is to copy your assembly to c:\ABC